# Cleaning a URL with PHP

Tags: stream, clean-urls

I've been looking though google and stackflow for an answer for this and testing a few finds but I still can't get this working.

All of these end my link at a space. For example [www.website.com/movies/movie](http://www.website.com/movies/movie) 
Where I'm trying to get it to read [www.website.com/movies/movie with spaces here.mp4](http://www.website.com/movies/movie%20with%20spaces%20here.mp4)

```
$namehref = "movie/" . $dirArray[$index]. " download";

$DoStream = "<a href=" . $the_dir . ">Watch</a>";
$DoDownload = "<a href=" . $the_dir . ">Download</a>";
```

---

However this code does **not** remove the spaces???

```
$name = $dirArray[$index];
$movienameonly = substr($name, 0, -4);
```

example www.website.com/movies/movie with spaces here

---

So my questions are - Why does the first section of code remove the spaces and how do I correct it. In addition to spaces I also hit errors with 's as well.  
*example They're here.mp4*

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spaces completely:

```
preg_replace("/\s/", "", $your_url);
```

To replace the spaces with `%20` (best way):

```
preg_replace("/\s/", "%20", $your_url);
```

To replace spaces with `+` like `url_encode($url)` does:

```
preg_replace("/\s/", "+", $your_url);
```

To replace `'` with `%27`:

```
preg_replace("/\s/", "%20", $your_url);
```

You get errors because spaces can't be inputted in the browser and converts the spaces to %20 and the apostrophe to %27

Comment: I can't figure out what is going on because it's still not working correctly. Your code does work, I was able to test it else wahere but I have something else going on here that I haven't found yet. 

When I right click on the link to view properties I see this,
<a href=​"movies/​30" minutes or less.mp4>​Watch Movie​</a>​

However, right next to it I am using the same code to grab the movie name which prints correctly "30 minutes or less". Any ideas of why it would do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it: 
`$DoStream = "<a href=" . $the_dir . ">Watch</a>";`

Should have been 
`$DoStream = "<a href='$the_dir'>Watch</a>";`